# list / string in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to parse tweets data.

My data shape is as follows:

```
59593936 3061025991 null null <d>2009-08-01 00:00:37</d> <s>&lt;a href="http://help.twitter.com/index.php?pg=kb.page&amp;id=75" rel="nofollow"&gt;txt&lt;/a&gt;</s> <t>honda just recalled 440k accords...traffic around here is gonna be light...win!!</t> ajc8587 15 24 158 -18000 0 0 <n>adrienne conner</n> <ud>2009-07-23 21:27:10</ud> <t>eastern time (us &amp; canada)</t> <l>ga</l>
22020233 3061032620 null null <d>2009-08-01 00:01:03</d> <s>&lt;a href="http://alexking.org/projects/wordpress" rel="nofollow"&gt;twitter tools&lt;/a&gt;</s> <t>new blog post: honda recalls 440k cars over airbag risk http://bit.ly/2wsma</t> madcitywi 294 290 9098 -21600 0 0 <n>madcity</n> <ud>2009-02-26 15:25:04</ud> <t>central time (us &amp; canada)</t> <l>madison, wi</l>
```

I want to get the total numbers of tweets and the numbers of keyword related tweets. I prepared the keywords in text file. In addition, I wanna get the tweet text contents, total number of tweets which contain mention(@), retweet(RT), and URL (I wanna save every URL in other file).

So, I coded like this.

```
import time
import os

total_tweet_count = 0
related_tweet_count = 0
rt_count = 0
mention_count = 0
URLs = {}

def get_keywords(filepath, mode):
    with open(filepath, mode) as f:
        for line in f:
            yield line.split().lower()

for line in open('/nas/minsu/2009_06.txt'):
    tweet = line.strip().lower()

    total_tweet_count += 1

    with open('./related_tweets.txt', 'a') as save_file_1:
        keywords = get_keywords('./related_keywords.txt', 'r')

        if keywords in line:
            text =  line.split('<t>')[1].split('</t>')[0]

            if 'http://' in text:
                try:
                    url = text.split('http://')[1].split()[0]
                    url = 'http://' + url

                    if url not in URLs:
                        URLs[url] = []
                    URLs[url].append('\t' + text)

                    save_file_3 = open('./URLs_in_related_tweets.txt', 'a')
                    print >> save_file_3, URLs

                except:
                    pass

            if '@' in text:
                mention_count +=1

            if 'RT' in text:
                rt_count += 1

            related_tweet_count += 1

            print >> save_file_1, text

    save_file_2 = open('./info_related_tweets.txt', 'w')

print >> save_file_2, str(total_tweet_count) + '\t' + srt(related_tweet_count) + '\t' + str(mention_count) + '\t' + str(rt_count)

save_file_1.close()
save_file_2.close()
save_file_3.close()
```

Following is the sample keywords

```
Depression
Placebo
X-rays
X-ray
HIV
Blood preasure
Flu
Fever
Oral Health
Antibiotics
Diabetes
Mellitus
Genetic disorders
```

I think my code has many problem, but the first error is as follows:

```
line 23, in <module> 
  if keywords in line: 
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not generator
```

I coded "def ..." part. I think it has a problem. When I try "print keywords" under line (keywords = get_keywords('./related_keywords.txt', 'r')), it gives something strange numbers not words.... . Please help me out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe change `if keywords in line:` to use a regular expression match instead. For example, something like:

```
import re
...
keywords = "|".join(get_keywords('./related_keywords.txt', 'r'))
matcher = re.compile(keywords)
if matcher.match(line):
  text =  ...
```

... And changed `get_keywords` to something like this instead:

```
def get_keywords(filepath, mode):
  keywords = []
  with open(filepath, mode) as f:
    for line in f:
      sp = line.split()
      for w in sp:
        keywords.append(w.lower())
  return keywords
```

Comment: Then I got this error on the "keywords = "|".join(get_keywords('./related_keywords.txt', 'r'))": TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, list found

Comment: Is there anybody who can make totally new code that give correct result? It's really hard for me ;_;

Comment: Do you need to use `yield`? Could you instead just build a list of words and return that?

Comment: I don't need to use yield. But I don't clearly understand how to code what you recommend. I need to study but I need a solution at the same time ;_;

Comment: I changed the answer to include a new `get_keywords` that builds a list.

Comment: Thank you very much! One more question here: can I change the keywords to lowercase? "return keywords.lower()" doesn't work for me.

Comment: I adjusted the answer to return lowercase words.